# Exit iteration of for loop Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, return, break

I have a function with a for loop inside of it:

```
func example() {
  // create tasks
  for link in links {
    let currIndex = links.indexOf(link)

    if let im = story_cache?.objectForKey(link) as? UIImage {
      if ((currIndex != nil) && (currIndex < content.count)) {
        if (content[currIndex!].resource_type == "image") {
          content[currIndex!].image = im
          return
        }
      }
    } else {
      if ((currIndex != nil) && (currIndex < content.count)) {
        if (content[currIndex!].resource_type == "video") {
          let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
          let documentsDirectory : NSString = paths[0]
          let appFile = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(content[currIndex!].id! + ".mov")
          let local_URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: appFile)
          if let cached_URL = story_cache?.objectForKey(local_URL) as? NSURL {
            content[currIndex!].videoURL = cached_URL
            return
          }
        }
      }
    }

    let dltask = session.dataTaskWithURL(link, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in  
      // MORE CODE.....
    })
  }
}
```

Basically what I wanna achieve is that if we reach any of the `return` statements the code finishes executing for this particular `link` in the loop, and the loop moves on to the next link. If NONE of the return statements are reached, I want the `dltask` to be executed. I could achieve this using a bunch of else statements but I think that would make the code quite messy. Am I doing this right with using `return`?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You're looking for `continue`:

From [Apple's Swift Book](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html):

> The continue statement tells a loop to stop what it is doing and start
>   again at the beginning of the next iteration through the loop. It says
>   “I am done with the current loop iteration” without leaving the loop
>   altogether.

Just replace `return` with `continue` and it will go back up to the `for` loop and run it again with the next link.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `break outer` or only `break` to exit the loop statement and execute the dltask .

hope it help .